# Yocto: how to remove a layer without rebuild all

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, bitbake

I'm playing with a Yocto project that has in its `conf/bblayers.conf` file the following line:

```
ADDONSLAYERS += "${@'${OEROOT}/layers/meta-qt5' if os.path.isfile('${OEROOT}/layers/meta-qt5/conf/layer.conf') else ''}"
```

I partially bitbaked the project but now I want to try to disable the whole meta-qt5 layer.
After commenting out the line above, how to remove the already built files from the output folder and go on with the others?

I tried with `bitbake -c cleansstate meta-qt5` but it doesn't work. I guess it works with recipes only, and not with whole layers.

Comment: What you can do is remove your `build/tmp` folder and use `sstate-cache` to rebuild it. Then you can clean `sstate-cache` with `sstate-cache-management.sh` script.

Comment: Would you mind to make your comment an answer providing a bit more details about the procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to clean a build is to remove [TMPDIR](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-TMPDIR) temporary folder (default is `<build>/tmp`).

That will remove previous compilation results, but those are also kept in [SSTATE_DIR](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SSTATE_DIR) cache folder. Next build will not rebuild all, it will reuse cache results to speed it up.

Then, you can clean your cache folder for obsolete entries with [sstate-cache-management.sh](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/scripts/sstate-cache-management.sh) script:

```
# Example of usage (after sourcing oe-init-build-env)
sstate-cache-management.sh --cache-dir=../sstate-cache -d -y
```