# Permission denied /tmp Yocto linux after deleting /tmp directory

Tags: yocto, bitbake

After following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140448/yocto-how-to-remove-a-layer-without-rebuild-all) to remove an unwanted layer from the image I removed the build/tmp directory and tried to run bitbake again. I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errono 13] Perrmission denied:'/tmp'
```

I tried to change permissions of the directory `chomd -R 777 build/tmp/` and run bitbake again, but the error persists. I also tried to run the `sstate-cache-management.sh`, but it has no effect.
Just for clarity, it seems that `/tmp` directory is created again during bitbak command, but it still fails after parsing all the recipes.
What can I do to still save my progress so far? I can always start from scratch, but I really don't want to build the kernel again.

Comment: Did you try: bitbake -c cleanall <fsl-image-xxx> Where <fsl-image-xxx> is your image. Also please check owner and group for other directories in the project. Are you sure that you are using the same user?

Comment: @kluszon Thank you for your comment, I just realized I'm an idiot. I accidentally deleted `/tmp` folder in root directory, not `build/tmp` folder. After creating `/tmp` folder again and setting proper permissions for it, the build process works again.

Comment: It sometimes happens ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, I accidentally deleted root `tmp` folder, not the folder in `build` directory. After creating it again and setting proper permissions, the build process works again.